# what is the different between 2 routing rules

Tags: routes

I see on my routing table that we have entries, and don't understand the different between the 2 rules. I think they are the same. Could you please explain.

```
default via 100.107.241.214 dev eth0.2
100.107.241.212/30 dev eth0.2  scope link
```

100.107.241.214 is the gateway address

Answer (score 0):

> default via 100.107.241.214 dev eth0.2

That the *default route* that's used when no other route applies (=no prefix matches the destination).

> 100.107.241.212/30 dev eth0.2  scope link

That's the route for *on-link* destinations = those hosts that share the same subnet. A /30 subnet has a total of four addresses, only two of which are usuable for hosts, 100.107.241.213 & 100.107.241.214 in your case. (For all prefix lengths except /31, the IP address with all 0s in the host part isn't normally usable, and the one with all 1s is the subnet broadcast address.)

For a subnet larger than /30 (=shorter prefix) this route determines whether the destination can be talked to directly or if the (default) gateway is required. /30 and /31 prefixes have only two usable addresses anyway.

Comment: The host portion of the IP address can now, on most systems, be all 1s or all 0s.  Refer to rfc2644 and cisco's docs for the "ip subnet-zero" command.  So point-to-point links (what the Internet core primarily consists of) now commonly have /31 subnets to save address space.

Comment: Another distinction made by cisco, and those schooled by them, is that the default route is used only if ip routing is disabled (with the "no ip routing" command (on by default but hidden on routers, off by default on some switches), or by the fact that the router is in RMON mode, aka bootstrap).  Whereas the 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 route they refer to as the route of last resort (the "rest of the world" calls it the default and many folks still do).  Just be careful on a cert exam or interview at a cisco shop.

Comment: @Andrew For IPv4, the host part can be all 0s only for a /31 P2P subnet or with (all) compatible devices. It can be all 1s only for a /31 subnet, and it is the subnet broadcast address for all others.

Comment: I think you're right, rfc2644 says they can't be used as source addr, just that routers can optionally forward them.  Sorry, I'm used to p2p.  ref. rfc3021.  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

"100.107.241.212/30 dev eth0.2  scope link"
Means:
if 100.107.241.212 & 255.255.255.252 = 100.107.241.212 == <destination IP address of outgoing packet> & 255.255.255.252 then
send that packet out the physical device ethernet 0 [on sub-interface .2 (probably vlan 2, 802.1Q encapsulation or a tunnel)?] (assuming this is the "longest bit" match).  scope link means these destinations are directly on the attached physical link, so an ARP request (unless it's already in the arp cache) will be sent to resolve the destination IP address of outgoing packet to the MAC address of the device that has that destination IP address, and that will be the destination MAC address of the frame(s) that contain the IP packet being sent.

"default via 100.107.241.214 dev eth0.2"
Means:
if there are no other route table matches (using the bit-wise AND tests shown above), send that packet out the physical device ethernet 0 [on sub-interface .2 (probably vlan 2, 802.1Q encapsulation or a tunnel)?]; since these destinations are not directly on the attached physical link (not local scope), an ARP request will be sent to resolve the next hop IP address, 100.107.241.214, (since it is the default route, it is also the gateway (GW) IP address) to the MAC address of the device that has that destination IP address (which should be a router), aka the GW's MAC, and that will be the destination MAC address of the frame(s) that contain the IP packet being sent.